# how to add class dynamically in navigation links with php?

Tags: php

i have this php function to change css class dynamically on my navigation link but i came with this error! Notice: Undefined variable: menuLinkid in C:\xampp\htdocs\Includes\vertical_menu.php on line 9 anyone has a idea why?

```
<?php 
$index="menu-items";
$Topalbums="menu-items";
$Topartists="menu-items";
$Toplists="menu-items";
$Charts="menu-items";
$memuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
if($menuLinkid=="index"){
$index='active';
}else if ($memuLinkid=="Topalbums"){
$Topalbums='active';
}else if ($memuLinkid=="Topartists"){
$Topartists='active';
}else if ($memuLinkid=="Toplists"){
$Toplists='active';
}else if ($memuLinkid=="Charts"){
$Charts='active';
}
?>
```

Comment: is it "menuLinkid" or "memuLinkid"?

Comment: There is a typo in your code:

Comment: spelling wrong $memuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `$memuLinkid` and not `$menuLinkid` in the definition. (A line above your error).

Answer (score 0):

Check where your setting this `$memuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");`  it has a typo in it, and if thats now the problem, then set a `var_dump($memuLinkid)` just below that line of code to see what its doing.

Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code:

```
$memuLinkid=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],".php");
```

should be

```
$menuLinkid=....
```